# Erase window background win32API

Tags: c++, winapi, background, erase

My classmates started using Delphi with pascal but I as c++ porgrammer have to use win32 API. They were changing background color so I need to know this aswell but there are some differencies.

In delphi each form looks like it has it's own instance, and setting background color for one window is just a matter of changing one value. Not the case with win32 where when you change that value it affects every window using that class (after update ofc).

What I need to do is to clear/erase my window background. I can do that with FillRect(..) and it's working very nicely, but I've found also [WM_ERASEBKGND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which seems to be doing exactly what I need. They mentioned that if this message gets proccessed I should return a non-zero, but they didn't tell how to process it.

So could anything else then FillRect(and similliar) let me erase a window with a brush I defined and not with the default for class?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to learn the Win API at this low level you should pick up a an old copy of "Programming Windows 3.1" by Charles Petzold (http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-3-1-Charles-Petzold/dp/1556153953) and see where Windows programming started.

Comment: where it started? Where it still is today. Just that we wrap it up with frameworks that do the dirty work.

Comment: @David - That's what I meant but just didn't phrase it very well :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You process `WM_ERASEBKGND` simply by erasing the background (using `FillRect()` is fine).

By returning a non-zero value, you are simply telling Windows that this message has been taken care of and no further action is needed. There is nothing more formal than that.

Comment: Yup as I said I can do that way. But isn't there anything like ClearBackground(handle, color) made specificaly for clearing? It's good to know FillRect() is right way, just curious.

Comment: ClearBackground == FillRect.  You do have to deal with writing more explicit code in win32.  Gotta make that brush first.  That's why almost anyone uses a class library.

Comment: @Raven - What do you think `ClearBackground` might be doing in it's method body, probably calling `FillRect()` :)

Comment: the delphi vcl will no doubt implement it this way. If you have a copy of the delphi source code then you could peruse it you your benefit. You should also read Petzold.

Comment: @Raven: What does FillRect() functionally do differently than ClearBackground()? Both set all pixels in a rectangle to a specified color. Do this for the entire client area (or update region) and the background is cleared. I'm not really sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: @Jonathan As I said I'm only beggining and I'm used to from openGL to have precise function for everything, but as Hans said it's going to be more explicit :) But I'll get used to that win32 later on.. @David not at the moment but I think it was like "Form1.background = ...." not very useful for me :/ @Hans what libraries you have on mind?

Comment: @Raven: That's fine. I'm just trying to make it clear. For C++/Windows, the most popular library is probably MFC.

Comment: @Jonathan Ah yes.. Well this is mainly for my exams where I'll be using Visual Studio Express (without MFC I believe) I need to know the "dirty way" as was mentioned.

Comment: @Raven: Then just handle WM_ERASEBKGND. Your app will be smaller and faster than just about any other Windows application out there.

Comment: @raven hans means things like vcl or mfc. All windows apps do this with FillRect. Frameworks and libraries hide it from you. If you want to learn read Petzold. I can't stress that enough.

Comment: @raven when in Delphi you write `Form1.BackgroundColor := ...` the framework remembers the colour and then calls `FillRect` with the appropriate colour the next time `WM_ERASEBKGND` comes around!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MFC with C++ you can also check out that framework's implementation of CWnd::OnEraseBkgnd
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz(v=vs.80).aspx